# wrapfigure - image jumps at documents end

Tags: wrapfigure

I'm new to LaTeX and I've got my first issue with wrapfigure. I want to have an image on the right side of my document. Text on the left.

```
HEADLINE
text text text text text
text text text text text
text text text IMAGE IMAGE
text text text IMAGE IMAGE
text text text IMAGE IMAGE
text text text text text
text text text text text
```

Therefore I use:

```
\section{Impressum}
\label{impressum}

\begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{6cm}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder}
\end{wrapfigure}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

But the Image only appears on the end of my document (even after my`listoffigures`.

I am wondering why because I used this code five times before this section and it works.

EDIT: Error Message: `Package wrapfig Warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line
233.`

LatexCode:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Bild}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2cm}

\title{TITLE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Einleitung}
\label{sec:einleitung}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\pagebreak
\section{App Konzept}
\label{sec:app-kozept}


\subsection{Lesen}
\label{subsec:lesen}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\subsection{Verwalten}
\label{subsec:verwalten}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\subsection{Navigation}
\label{subsec:navigation}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/adddata_full}}
    \caption[Ausgefülltes Daten hinzufügen Fragment]{Ausgefülltes Daten         hinzufügen Fragment}
    \label{fig:adddatafull}

    \vspace{20pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedrooms_full}}
    \caption[Gespeicherte Räume]{Gespeicherte Räume}
    \label{fig:savedrooms}
\end{wrapfigure}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 



\pagebreak
\subsection{Standortverwaltung}
\label{subsec:standwortverwaltung}

\begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[Gespeicherte Standorte]{Gespeicherte Standorte}
    \label{fig:savedlocations}

    \vspace{20pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations_fabs}}
    \caption[Fabs des Fragments]{Fabs des Fragments}
    \label{fig:savedlocations-fabs}
\end{wrapfigure}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 



\pagebreak
\section{Impressum}
\label{impressum}

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder}
\end{wrapfigure}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\pagebreak
\listoffigures


\end{document}
```

EDIT2: Result if I add another Figure:

```
\section{Impressum}
\label{impressum}

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/placeholder}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/placeholder}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder}
\end{wrapfigure}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you really need to shorten `43` lines? It's about the total number of lines in a normal page.

Comment: Yes youre right. But one page earlier I had two pictures in one wrapfigure so I needed the 43 lines. But even with 20 or 10 or zero the Image jumps to the end.

Comment: The image is inserted near the bottom of the page?

Comment: No. The `\section` is the first thing I added on a fresh page

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non)working  code, so we can play with it? Note that, for the width, you should replace `6cm` with `0cm`: `wrapfig` will then use the natural width of the figure (0.3\textwidth).

Comment: What do you mean with (non)working code? I forgot to add the Error Message ... `Package wrapfig Warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line
233.`

Comment: A fully compilable and minimalistic LaTeX code.

Comment: @Bernard I added some Code

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: I obtain the same figure as @Herbert.

Comment: It seems like the problem only effects the last figure in the document .. but how could this be?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your figure is too big. The following setting with `width=` and
`height=` is only for some demonstration. Often one needs `keepaspectratio=true` when using both options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \section{Impressum}
    \label{impressum}

    \begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{0.4\textwidth}\centering
        \vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth,height=39\normalbaselineskip]{screens/savedlocations}}
        \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
        \label{fig:placeholder}
    \end{wrapfigure}        
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\Blindtext      
\end{document}
```

[image]

For two figures use:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{0.4\textwidth}\centering
    \vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth,height=18\normalbaselineskip]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder}
    \bigskip
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth,height=18\normalbaselineskip]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[placeholder]{placeholder}
    \label{fig:placeholder2}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: I dont get it ... I dont think that the figure is too big. Because It works ~20 miles above with the same code. I will add another image to my question because with another figure it gets more and more curious.

Comment: If you have two figures then put *both* in *one* `\wrapfigure` environment (see edited answer)

Comment: normally I use just one `\wrapfigure` this was just for test purpose

Answer (score 1):

I got it! The problem was the wrapfigure above.

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}[43]{h}[0cm]{0cm}
    \vspace{-12pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations}}
    \caption[Gespeicherte Standorte]{Gespeicherte Standorte}
    \label{fig:savedlocations}

    \vspace{20pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{screens/savedlocations_fabs}}
    \caption[Fabs des Fragments]{Fabs des Fragments}
    \label{fig:savedlocations-fabs}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I shortened 43 line but the page wasnt full. So the `\wrapfigure` laped into the next page -.-

Comment: You can use the undocumented \WFclear to stop that from happening.